# Select from left join with multiple cte blocks

Tags: sql, postgresql

The `odr` cte gets `num` where `code` is `1`. The `adv` cte gets `num` where `code` is `2`. `comm` and `medi` cte's do the same where `code` is `3` and `4` respectively. The `total` cte gets counts of all `nums` regardless of the `code`.

```
with odr (num, odr_count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code = '1'
group by num
),
adv (num, adv_count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code = '2'
group by num
),comm (num, comm_count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code = '3'
group by num
),medi (num, medi_count) as 
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
where 
code = '4'
or 
code = '5'
group by num
),
total (num, tot_count) as
(
SELECT num, count(*)
FROM pay t
group by num
)
select t.num, tot_count, o.num, 
o.odr_count, adv.num, adv_count, 
c.num, comm_count, 
medi.num, medi_count
FROM total t
left join odr o
on t.num = o.num
left join adv
on o.num = adv.num
left join comm c
on medicaid.num = c.num
left join medi
on c.num = medi.num
```

This is the output of this query -

```
Num     tot_count    num    odr_count   adv.num    adv_count   c.num    comm_count    medi.num   medi_count
14476   10                                              
15082   156
```

Why do all the other columns not have data?

I would expect a result like this

```
Num     tot_count    num    odr_count   adv.num    adv_count   c.num    comm_count    medi.num   medi_count
14476   10           14476  35345       14476      234         14476    343246        14476      8
15082   156          15082  4354        NULL       NULL        15082    3432
```

I am expecting NULL and empty columns in the second row because `15082` does not have all the `codes` from `1 through 4`.

Comment: your `t.num` `14476` does not equal your `o.num` of `23` and your join explicitly says it must: `FROM total t
left join odr o
on t.num = o.num`. To get your desired results, how do you determine which nums go on which of your two lines. It looks like "Randomly grab whatever num from each cte you wish and fill out the record. Only make two records". Which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JNevill I am sorry it does equal. I had just put in dummy data. I will put in real data to avoid confusion.

Comment: If ycu could also please share sample data to match your desired results from your `pay` table so we can track this through and replicate. It might be a good idea to run simple SELECTs against your CTEs to troubleshoot as well. Like `SELECT * FROM odr` and make sure the nums outputted match the nums from `SELECT * FROM total`. Other than that, I see nothing wrong with your SQL. This feels like an issue with your data or your assumptions about it.